# Tuning Apache Camel JMS router performance

Tags: apache-camel

At the point when I execute routing-to-a-JMS-queue as below

```
.inOut("jmsGF:queue:INQueue?replyTo=queue:OUTQueue")
```

I observe that Camel needs about 900ms before it could actually send the message to the JMS queue. Is there a way to reduce this process/config time? Thanks.

```
2012-04-30 14:51:22,098 SendProcessor Endpoint[jmsGF://queue:INQueue?replyTo=queue:OUTQueue]
2012-04-30 14:51:22,833 Configuration$CamelJmsTemplate - Executing callback on JMS Session: ConnectionID=7685453259737775872, SessionID=7685453259737832448
2012-04-30 14:51:22,973 JmsConfiguration - Sending JMS message to: Oracle GlassFish(tm) Server MQ Destination
```

Comment: I resolved delay by using org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory (ref: http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-spring-jmstemplate-to-send-jms.html)

Comment: Thanks for your investigation!

Answer (score 0):

as you found, the key is to use some form of connection pooling of the JMS producer connections

also, beware of using the Spring CachingConnectionFactory for consumer connections as it can cause issues (especially with polling consumers, etc)

see this page for general info: http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use Camel 2.9, then you can use exclusive replyTo queues which is also faster. See details about request/reply over JMS at the Camel JMS wiki page. It also have pointers how to improved performance for older releases, and when you cannot use exclusive reply to queues.
http://camel.apache.org/jms

Comment: The Exclusive replyto feature is really nice for performance. This was for sending, not the response. It would be nice to see some out of container caching of JMS sessions built into Camel with less dependency to manual spring config. I will probably put up a camel feature request for this some time.

Comment: So Exclusive replyTo is a way of ignoring Selector with JMSCorrelationID, which is indeed faster on receiving the jms responses. BTW, `.inOut().to("activemq:queue:foo?replyTo=bar?replyToType=Exclusive")` in Camel JMS wiki has a typo "?" in front of "replyToType". It should be "&" (I hope someone has super editing power could correct it :-)

Comment: Yeah a generic JMS caching pool would be nice. Also for ppl not wanna drag in Spring just for that. A new simpler JMS component is in the works that is non Spring dependent, eg just using plain JMS API.

Comment: I have fixed the typos in the examples.